# Execute sql from vbscript

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I wanted to execute the below SQL Script on local SQL Express server:

```
Select *
from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\localpath\file.xlsx;', 
[Sheet1$])
```

Query run from SQL Express works fine. But when I try to run it from vbscript:

```
dim dbconn, ConnectionString
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=compname\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB;ID=username;Password="";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"
Set dbconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open ConnectionString
dbconn.Execute("\\path\query.sql")
```

it displays following error:

> **Script:** Script path 
>   **Line:** 4
>  
>   **Char:** 1
>   **Error:** Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. 
>   **Code:** 800A0BB9 
>   **Source:** ADODB.Connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct connection string:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=compname\SQLEXPRESS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to have a single quote for password as two quotes in a string are treated as 1.

> ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=compname\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB;ID=username;**Password=""**;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"

Comment: Good point. I have changed that to single quote but there is still an error, different however:
**Error:** Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.

Comment: And I have found another apostrphe missing in _Properties='Excel 12.0'_. After filling this in I am getting the "Could not find installable ISAM." error. Any clues?

Comment: Here is a web site of connection strings. https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: The connection string is correct. But now I get error saying: "ActiveX component can't create object: OLEDB.Connection"

Comment: Use the Query Helper in Excel. Alt + D, D, N, then double click Excel, browse, choose options, then chosse to edit query at end of wizard. Then in Editor File Save. This text file will have a connection string and sql string in it.